# 500 internal server error при редактировании php файла

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ios

Занимаюсь доработкой приложения, нашел ошибку в бэкенде, подключился через файлзилу, заменил в файле строку и теперь:

```
2016-03-23 18:38:51.878 Social_Event[984:485926] Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0., NSUnderlyingError=0x175d4010 {Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: internal server error (500)" UserInfo={com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x1bb17800> { URL: http://....compute.amazonaws.com/ws/user/driverstatus } { status code: 500, headers {
Connection = close;
"Content-Length" = 1396;
"Content-Type" = "application/json";
Date = "Wed, 23 Mar 2016 15:37:17 GMT";
Server = "Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)";
"X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14";
} },      NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://....compute.amazonaws.com/ws/user/driverstatus, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: internal server error (500), com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<
```

Функцию driverstatus не трогал. Клиент обращается к этому файлу при логине, но при обращении к этой функции ломается. Вернул исходный файл, ошибка осталась. Права доступа файла такие же как и у остальных в данной папке, кодировку через сублайм при сохранении ставил UTF-8 без bom.

```
    function driverstatus() {

$iUserID = intVal($this->input->get_post("iUserID"));
$status = $this->input->get_post('status');

 $sql = "UPDATE  `ridehost`.`tbl_user` SET  `onlineornot` = '$status' WHERE  `tbl_user`.`iUserID` = ".$iUserID.";";

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);


        $responseData['status'] = "0";

        $responseData['data'] = array();

        $responseData['message'] = "Updated Successfully";

    je($responseData);

}
```

Comment: Приветствую. Если REST клиентом обращаться, то работает?

Comment: Попробовал, Error Number: 1146

Table 'ridehost.tbl_user' doesn't exist

UPDATE  `ridehost`.`tbl_user` SET  `onlineornot` = '' WHERE  `tbl_user`.`iUserID` = 0;

Filename:.../user.php

Line Number: 1459

Comment: Здесь проблема не в iOS, а на backend-е не отрабатывает SQL запрос - сообщает, что таблицы `ridehost.tbl_user` не существует

Comment: Я и не думал что проблема в клиенте. В общем каким то образом до редактирвоания php файла, она видела таблицу ridehost.tbl_user, хотя на деле это просто tbl_user без ridehost. Решил удалением из запроса строки ridehost. Спасибо за помощь!